# Local account and option for Azure AD authentication using IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, identityserver3

I'm new to IdentityServer. We have a requirement for the application to allow access to multiple web APIs. As of now authentication is done locally with a database and there is alternate way to get authenticated by Azure AD.

I want my dashboard app to authenticate using IdentityServer3 (which is working fine as of now) and alternatively using external provider (Azure AD in this case).

However I keep getting

> There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again

The configuration for server, I'm using CustomViewService [found at here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService)

I'm adding Azure AD to the list of external providers:

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{

  ClientId = "xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-04ec8dbxxxx",
  Authority = "https://login.windows.net/[domain name]",
  RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44333/core",
  PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:36336/",
  AuthenticationType = "Azure AD",
  Caption = "Azure AD",
  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    NameClaimType = "name",
    RoleClaimType = "role"
  },
  SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

  Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
  {
    MessageReceived = m =>
    {
      var split = m.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;
      return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
      context.HandleResponse();
      context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
      return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
    {
      context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "[domain name here]";
      return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm presented with Azure AD log in screen, after which application is diverted back to IdentityServ3 at `https://localhost:44333/core/callback`

My client is at `http://localhost:36336/`

Client configuration is:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
  });

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    ClientId = "mvc.owin.hybrid.2",
    Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:36336/",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:36336/",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = "openid profile read write offline_access",

    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      NameClaimType = "name",
      RoleClaimType = "role"
    },

    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
      AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
      {
        // use the code to get the access and refresh token
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
        "https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token",
        "mvc.owin.hybrid.2",
        "secret");

        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
        n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
          throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
        new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
        tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

        // create new identity
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
        id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims);

        id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
        new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
      },

      RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
      {
        // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
        {
          var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

          if (idTokenHint != null)
          {
            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
          }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you do a Fiddler trace or use developer tools (F12) to see what Azure AD is responding back to IdentityServer? Is Azure AD sending a token back or an error message?

Comment: azure ad is working correctly and I checked logs on azure abt user authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out.

I forgot to implement  `AspNetIdentityUserService` specially the method `AuthenticateExternalAsync`

Once I mapped the user and claims from Azure to the local user it worked.

Furthermore, if you need to hide local login screen and want your client to directly go to Azure AD login screen make sure to set `EnableLocalLogin` to false in Client properties